# When I do a git checkout of a branch from origin why is a subsequent pull needed to get latest?

Tags: git

I have done the following command

```
git checkout -b mylocalbranch origin/develop
```

I know that mylocalbranch does not have the latest commits on develop. After

git pull --ff-only

it appears I have all the commits. So am correct about this and if so, what commits are reflected in mylocalbranch after the checkout but before the pull?

Comment: I normally wouldn't pull on a branch created this way.  Instead, just `git fetch` and then explicitly merge or rebase with `develop`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But can you explain what is happening? Do the steps I am taking result in something unexpected/undesirable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout` does not interact with any remotes, it only operates within your local repository. This means that your command will create a new branch (`mylocalbranch`) and sets it to point to wherever your local remote tracking branch `origin/develop` is currently pointing to. When you do a `git pull` or `git fetch`, the remote tracking branches are updated.

The subsequent pull was in your case needed because since the last time you pulled or fetched, new commits had appeared on the remote's `develop` branch.

Comment: This is great. Makes sense.